# Child element overflow results in button in different container running away from mouse when hovered

Tags: css, flexbox

See the below snippet. Whenever the mouse is moved over the button, the `.nested-tall` expands for some reason, and the whole `.tall` container resizes, so the button is no longer where the mouse is, and is not clickable, at least with the mouse.

```css
body {
  position: fixed; /* Just for the sake of a minimal example */
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body .tall {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body .tall .nested-tall {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <div class="nested-tall">
    I am Tall
  </div>
  <div>
    I am invisible due to overflow
  </div>
</div>
<button>Hover me</button>
```

The solution is simple: don't have the children overflow their `.tall` container. But what exactly is going on here? Why does the change of the border color of the button result in the `.nested-tall` height changing? The button is not only in a completely different container, but the change is only to *color*, not to anything that should affect the box model.

If you open the browser console in the snippet editor, you'll see that even just resizing the *console pane* results in button moving, which is quite strange.

Giving the button a border color when not hovered incidentally fixes it:

```css
body {
  position: fixed; /* Just for the sake of a minimal example */
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body .tall {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body .tall .nested-tall {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
button {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <div class="nested-tall">
    I am Tall
  </div>
  <div>
    I am invisible due to overflow
  </div>
</div>
<button>Hover me</button>
```

As does using some properties *other* than `border-color` on hover:

```css
body {
  position: fixed; /* Just for the sake of a minimal example */
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body .tall {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body .tall .nested-tall {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <div class="nested-tall">
    I am Tall
  </div>
  <div>
    I am invisible due to overflow
  </div>
</div>
<button>Hover me</button>
```

As does removing the text "I am invisible due to overflow" at the bottom of `.tall`:

```css
body {
  position: fixed; /* Just for the sake of a minimal example */
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body .tall {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body .tall .nested-tall {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <div class="nested-tall">
    I am Tall
  </div>
  <div>
    
  </div>
</div>
<button>Hover me</button>
```

What exactly is causing this odd behavior on hover, or when the console is resized?

Comment: If this happens not to be a duplicate, I'll award a bounty to a good answer.

Comment: we can make it more funny by removing the flex-grow:1 ... you will still have the issue

Comment: also note that this only happen on Chrome, Firefox is ok. This is for sure a bug and it's related to the use of height:100%. I don't actually have an accurate explanation but you are facing a cycle calculation that make the height:100% growing on each iteration.

Comment: Oh good, if it's actually a bug and not intended behavior, I guess the "why" doesn't really matter

Comment: the bug seems to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The bug is fixed, no need to read the below!**

<sup>PS: the below is my own intrepretation of what I think is a bug on Chrome related to flexbox and percentage height</sup>

Here is a more simplified example of your issue:

```css
body {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body .tall .nested-tall {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <div class="nested-tall">
    I am Tall
  </div>
  <div style="height:1px"></div>
</div>
<button>Hover me</button>
```

Note how on hovering you are increasing the size by exactly `1px` which is the size of the overflowing div. To be more accurate, it's the total overflowing size (`100% + 1px - 100%`).

When you add a `border-color` to the button you change it's layout so you will trigger a reflow of the page (exactly like if you resize the screen). This will trigger the calculation of the `height:100%` again the trick is here.

The parent element don't have any height specified so technically the use of `100%` on the child element should fail (it's the case on Firefox) but Chrome is calculating this considering the height of the parent BUT the height of the parent is calculated based on the content (we have a cycle here). Initially, we have the size of the parent element equal to the size of the text and `1px` then the nested div will take that size as its own (due to the `height:100%`) and we will have our overflowing `1px`.

Now imagine the next iteration. the size of the parent is now bigger with `1px` from the intial size and this one will be used to calculate the `height:100%` of the text and again `1px` of overflow and so on.

This is indeed very odd and should be considered as a *serious* **bug**. The use of `height:100%` in this case should either fall to `auto` or consider the initial layout without considering different values each time.

---

Your other snippets don't trigger this behivor because in some of them you are no more changing the layout of the button (like changing the color or having the border intially) and in one of them you have an empty div overflowing so each time you will add `0px` and nothing will happen.

Comment: I did consider the possibility that the border color was changing the button size, but it doesn't look like there's a difference when looking at the elements with Chrome's Computed tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvMup.png Does it actually cause a size change somewhere? (it sounds very intuitive that it *does*, because it's causing the issue, but I don't see it there)

Comment: @Snow you are right, it's not really the *size* but the look of the button. I thought it was the size but seems to be a simple optical illusion